# Align separate tables horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a number of dynamically generated tables that should align horizontally. Tables columns are grouped together and have a group name most of the time. But when they don't, I cannot get the tables to align horizontally, the table head minimum height isn't respected. My code:

```
<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                    col group 1
            </th>

            <th colspan="2">
                    col group 2
            </th>            
        </tr>    
        <tr class="title">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Columna</th>
            <th>Relative</th>
            <th>Isso</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>This</td>
            <td>Column</td>
            <td>Is</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">

            </th>

            <th colspan="2">

            </th>            
        </tr>    
        <tr class="title">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Columna</th>
            <th>Relative</th>
            <th>Isso</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>    
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>This</td>
            <td>Column</td>
            <td>Is</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
th,td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
tr.title th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

table{
    margin-right: 30px;
    float:left;
}

thead{
     min-height:86px;   
}

th{
     min-height: 50%;   
}
```

This jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q5e7dvzc/1/). If you take a look, you'll see the second table doesn't align horizontally with the first. How can I ensure the tables align, even if now column group name is provided? Note the tables are dynamic, I do not know how many there will be, how many columns etc.

Comment: You have an error on your HTML. You haven't closed the < thead > on both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so try setting `height` on `th` instead of `min-height`

```
th{
height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove min-height from `thead and th` and use specific `height` for `th` like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q5e7dvzc/3/)**

```
th {
    height: 50px;
}
```